# How to scale bitmap to hold same screen space

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, dpi

I have Bitmap which I need to resize at runtime. And it's size must be resized so, that it will hold same screen space at any screen. I tried to use dp like so:

```
private int dpiToPx(int dp) {
    //return (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * dp / 160f);
    return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And scale bitmap:

```
Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (
       b1,
       dpiToPx(225),
       dpiToPx(225),
       true
);
```

Later I will draw it using canvas.drawBitmap();

I was thinking that it will produce same sized bitmap at any screen. But testing on 320dpi screen and 720 dpi screen gives large difference.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

using sdp library may help you. https://github.com/intuit/sdp

```
    Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap ( b1, 
    dpiToPx(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._225sdp)),
    dpiToPx(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._225sdp)), true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to determine the height and width of your device and use it in .createScaledBitmap

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```